# activemq network broker different version

Tags: networking, activemq-classic, broker

i have an activemq network of broker using activemq 5.4.0. I have a central server with a broker and a consumer and many client with local broker and producer.
I need to upgrade activemq to version 5.8.0.
Upgrading the server, in local broker i continue to see central consumer, but messages remain in local broker.

For a netowork of broker, it's mandatory to have same version of activemq?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved in this way:

1) change configuration in network connector broker client 5.4.0 from

```
<networkConnectors>                       
     <networkConnector uri="static://(tcp://SERVERURL:61616)"
            name="bridge"
            duplex="true"
            conduitSubscriptions="true"
            decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="false">                               
     </networkConnector>
</networkConnectors>
```

to

```
<networkConnectors>                       
    <networkConnector uri="static://(tcp://SERVERURL:61616)"
            name="bridge"
            duplex="true"
            conduitSubscriptions="true"
            decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="false">               
            <dynamicallyIncludedDestinations>
                    <queue physicalName=">" />
            </dynamicallyIncludedDestinations>
     </networkConnector>
</networkConnectors>
```

2) upgrade server broker from 5.4.0 to 5.8.0
3) All works, also synchronous messages
4) Upgrade each broker client to 5.8.0 and test every message

Answer (score 0):

Yes, mixing broker versions in a network of brokers is not a good idea.  The testing done is always done using the same versions of the Broker.

Comment: i made some tests:

- if i upgrade server and client together to 5.8.0 all works, but i can't upgrade all because i have a lot of client.

- if i upgrade server to 5.8.0 and clients stay to 5.4.0, in client admin i can see active remote consumer, but produced messages remain in local broker.

- if i upgrade client to 5.8.0 and server stays to 5.4.0, async messages work, but request-reply messages don't work: server receive message, but client has no response. 

Any idea for a particular configuration?
Which is the best practice for a massive upgrade? I have one server and at least 100 clients.